# unknown exception with a push method

Tags: java, exception

I'm getting an error with a push method but I can't find the problem in the method and the code connected to it. The message is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at stack.Stackmethod.newObject(Stackmethod.java:71)
at stack.Stackmethod.push(Stackmethod.java:24)
at stack.StackMain.main(StackMain.java:10)
```

and the code that is specified is:

Line 71:

```
private void newObject() {
    Object[] arr = new Object[tmp.length + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
        arr[i + 1] = tmp[i];
    }
    arr = tmp;
}
```

Line 24:

```
@Override
public void push(Object element) {
    newObject();
    tmp[0] = element;
}
```

Line 4:

```
public class Stackmethod implements Stack{
    Object [] tmp;
```

Main:

```
public class StackMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Stackmethod stc = new Stackmethod();


        stc.push(7);
        System.out.println(stc.toString());
```

If someone could explain what is wrong, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Apparently tmp is null.

Comment: i used it to store different values

Comment: post more code please. with this portion it is not possible no evaluate it.

Comment: So you declared an array `tmp` but never initialized it? You know that this is necessary, because you did it correctly here `Stackmethod stc = new Stackmethod();`. So think about it and you'll find the answer.

Comment: where did you initialize tmp?

Comment: another thing, how is it unknown error when it says java.lang.NullPointerException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize your "tmp" array:

```
public class Stackmethod implements Stack{
    Object [] tmp = new Object[SOME_LENGTH_DEPENDING_ON_HOW_YOU_USE_IT];
```

In Java Object[] tmp is just a reference to an array and by default it is initialized to null. If you try to access an element via such a reference you will get NullPointerException.

Comment: thanks it worked :) im very new to this so i didnt know.

Comment: i dont have enough rep for that need 15 i have 4 XD